# Recreating PyCharm launcher in Ubuntu

Tags: bash, ubuntu, pycharm

I installed pycharm normally via `bin/pycharm.sh`, but the mistake I made was doing `bash pycharm.sh` *while* the pycharm directory has inside the Downloads folder.

I later on moved the directory to `/opt/Pycharm/`. This is causing the once functioning unity launcher (which was added when PyCharm was initially installed) to fail every time I attempt to use it (as expected).

How can I re-add `pycharm.sh` as a lauchable app from the unity launcher? I know the location of the `pycharm.sh` file. I've tried to add it to `/usr/bin/` but that does not change anything.

I can still launch pycharm via `bash /usr/opt/Pycharm/bin/Pycharm.sh`. But this is tedious.

### UPDATE

I have tried making a new `.desktop` file for pycharm, using the following script:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=PyCharm
Exec=/opt/Pycharm-3.0.1/bin/pycharm.sh
Icon=/opt/Pycharm-3.0.1/bin/PyCharm_32.png
Type=Application
Categories=Development;
StartupWMClass=PyCharm
```

However, I get a "Unable to save Pycharm.desktop" error when I try to save the file inside `/usr/share/applications/pycharm.desktop`. Any help regarding this would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: A workaround - get into your Downloads folder, and run `ln -s /opt/Pycharm-3.0.1`. Now the `charm` script is happy. But see below.

Answer (score 186, accepted):

First start `pyCharm` from it's bin folder via command line

`$ ./pycharm.sh`

Then, goto

`Tools -> Create Desktop Entry`.

It will create a correct Desktop file in the correct place. Afterward you can initiate it from the menu and pin the icon or drag and drop it to the bar. This way, you don't have to deal with `.desktop` files and mumbo jumbo..

Comment: After the update from pycharm 3 to 4, I had to delete `.local/share/applications/jetbrains-pycharm.desktop`. Then I could create a new one.

Comment: If you run it with `sudo` then the configuration settings end up in `/root/`...  I don't think that's what you want to do.  If you run it as the regular user with sudo rights then it prompts for a password when you run "Create Desktop Entry"

Comment: There is no "Tools -> Create Desktop Entry" in PyCharm 2017.3.3 (Community Edition).

Answer (score 14):

I managed to solve it. The thing is, Pycharm already installs a launcher inside `.local/share/applications`. Thus, you need to get rid of it before proceeding to create your own. After that, all you have to do is add your own `*.desktop` file to the `applications` directory inside `usr/share/applications/`.

You need to create your `.desktop` file using `sudo` and inside the desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=PyCharm
Exec=/opt/pycharm-3.0.1/bin/pycharm.sh
Icon=/opt/pycharm-3.0.1/bin/pyCharm.png  # Changed from pycharm_32.png
Type=Application
Categories=Development;
StartupWMClass=PyCharm
```

After that is done, you can launch your app properly. Please note that `pycharm.sh` must also have execution rights.

Answer (score 6):

With Ubuntu 16.04, I used the "snap" installer, which doesn't include an easily accessible icon (there's probably one hidden inside the snap image, but it's hard to get at). Instead it shows a grey question mark icon in the launcher instead. Also there doesn't seem to be a **Tools > Create Desktop Entry** option in version 2017.3.3 as far as I can see - maybe it has been moved somewhere.

So I copied `pycharm.png` from an earlier non-snap Community installation, saved it somewhere, then created `~/.local/share/applications/jetbrains-pycharm-ce.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=PyCharm Community Edition
Icon=/path/to/pycharm.png
Exec="/snap/bin/pycharm-community" %f
Comment=The Drive to Develop
Categories=Development;IDE;
Terminal=false
StartupWMClass=jetbrains-pycharm-ce
```

Then when I start PyCharm (from the command line), the launcher item appears with the correct icon, and then I right-click on it and choose "Lock to Launcher", and it now persists.

A downside is that the icon will not be automatically updated with the app, so it might fall out of date.

Answer (score 3):

In case you just want to update your launcher to point to an updated PyCharm, for me changing 4.0.4 to 4.0.6 in the following worked:

```
nano /usr/share/applications/jetbrains-pycharm.desktop
```

Answer (score 3):

**When Tools -> Create Desktop Entry does not work:**
Create a new file on your desktop (using vi or a similar command) named:
 **jetbrains-pycharm.desktop**

Paste the following inside:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=PyCharm
Icon=/opt/pycharm-5.0.1/bin/pycharm.png
Exec="/opt/pycharm-5.0.1/bin/pycharm.sh" %f
Comment=Develop with pleasure!
Categories=Development;IDE;
Terminal=false
StartupWMClass=jetbrains-pycharm
```

Keep in mind to change the path and version number of **icon** and **exec** properties above.

Tested on various versions of PyCharm - like a charm ☺

Comment: worked for me - using Ubuntu 16.04 and Pycharm 2018.1.1 - thank you !

Answer (score 1):

In the 2016 version of PyCharm just do following:

1. Start PyCharm.
2. From the Tools menu, select "Create Desktop Entry..."
3. Create entry for "all the users" if required.
4. Relaunch PyCharm from Launcher.

Comment: No launcher is created in Ubuntu 16.04, PyCharm 2016.1.

Answer (score 1):

**Ubuntu 16.04** (haven't checked prior versions)

Run `pycharm.sh` (make sure you use the correct dir and PyCharm version below):

```
$ ./dir_where_you_placed_it/pycharm-2016.1.4/bin/pycharm.sh
```

While PyCharm is running, right click its icon on the Launcher and select `"lock to Launcher"`.

Answer (score 1):

Run `$ pycharm-community`
Right after you will see the icon on the `taskbar`.
Right Click, select `Lock on the Taskbar`.
Somewhat solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Simply replaced the `Icon=/path/to/pycharm.png`in `~/.local/share/applications/jetbrains-pycharm-ce.desktop` from meowsqueak's answer with the correct path when installed from snap.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=PyCharm Community Edition
Icon=/snap/pycharm-community/current/bin/pycharm.png
Exec="/snap/bin/pycharm-community" %f
Comment=The Drive to Develop
Categories=Development;IDE;
Terminal=false
StartupWMClass=jetbrains-pycharm-ce
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo vim `which charm`
```

Now edit the `RUN_PATH`.

Comment: I'm afraid this does not open up anything :( How can I create a .desktop file from scratch?

Comment: no idea why you insist on clicking something when you should have a bash open, but see my symlink trick.

Comment: Well, there _is_ a bash inside pycharm, so there's no point in keeping an extra terminal open.

Answer (score 0):

I recently resolved a related issue where, after updating from v2.7 to v3.0.2, my PyCharm launcher was still pointing to the old (and now deleted) PyCharm path.
After attempting all of the (good) advice above, the problem still persisted.
The solution, in my case, was to create a desktop entry for ALL USERS.
[Welcome Screen]->Configure->Create Desktop Entry...
Check the box: **"Create entry for all users"** and then proceed.

Apparently, in a previous installation I must have installed it in this fashion and was not able to update the launcher for a single account.

Answer (score 0):

Now the pycharm updated to version 2016.1 and I find the file `jetbrains-pycharm.desktop` in the path `~/.local/share/applications`

then just edit the path for `Icon` and `Exec`

Answer (score 0):

Simply type this on your terminal window:

```
jetbrains-pycharm.desktop
```

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add, I just installed PyCharm Edu for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS today, and the way to create a desktop entry is very easy. When PyCharm Edu opens up, before entering any project, click on configure, and there should be a create Desktop Entry option. Select it, and it will create a PyCharm Edu.desktop file in the following directory:

```
/usr/local/share/applications
```

Now traverse to that destination, and click the newly created PyCharm Edu.desktop file to launch PyCharm Edu. After that, you would just need to lock to launcher. It should work.

I know I am very late, but I hope I've helped those of us on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS who are trying to configure a desktop entry for this specific application.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you didn't check **'Create the entry for all users (requires superuser privileges)'** option on Tools -> Create Desktop Entry. You should check it.

You don't have to create something new.

Answer (score 0):

you can always use python for automation
may be this will help you
a python script that allows u to run pycharm as user or sudoers/root

```
    import os
    from time import sleep
    sleep(1)
    program = input('which program to run: >')

    if program == "pycharm":
        os.chdir('#full path to pycharm paste here')
        root = input('run as root(y/n): >')
        if root == 'y':
            print('started ' + program + ' as root')
            sleep(0.5)
            print('please enter root password to continue:')
            os.system('sudo ./pycharm.sh')
        elif root == 'n':
            print('running ' + program + ' as non root')
            os.system('./pycharm.sh')
    elif program != 'pycharm':
        print('program not found')
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an LXDE desktop (on Debian Buster) and using PyCharm CE 2020.2.3. Choosing *Create Desktop Entry...* created nothing on the desktop, no matter whether *Create the entry for all users* was checked or not.

However, the PyCharm menu entry (under *Programming*) offers a context menu entry *Add to desktop*. Clicking this finally made the desktop icon appear.